# Android - Moving a View around works in API > 11 but fails with lower versions

Tags: android

I have a simple layout:

```
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/lrrh_top_layout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.235" />
        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.22">
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.05" />
            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lrrh_red_dress"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_weight="0.14"
                android:background="@drawable/lrrh_seq01_obj_red_dress" />
            <TextView
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:layout_weight="0.79" />
        </LinearLayout>
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            android:layout_weight="0.565" />
    </LinearLayout>
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lrrh_drag_item"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@drawable/lrrh_seq01_obj_red_dress"
        android:visibility="invisible" /> </FrameLayout>
```

Where I am moving a TextView around the screen whenever it's touched. For this purpose I set on event on TextView to catch the "Touch" event and then set to visible another textview that is on another layer, and move it around.
It works perfectly for API > 11 but fails for any version below.
How come?

```
    TextView redDress = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lrrh_red_dress);

    redDress.Touch += (s, e) =>
    {
        TextView touched = (TextView) s;
        TextView dragItem = FindViewById<TextView>(Resource.Id.lrrh_drag_item);

        int x = (int)e.Event.RawX;
        int y = (int)e.Event.RawY;
        switch (e.Event.ActionMasked)
        {
            case MotionEventActions.Move:
                touched.Visibility = ViewStates.Invisible;
                dragItem.SetBackgroundDrawable(touched.Background);
                int width = touched.Width;
                int height = touched.Height;
                dragItem.Visibility = ViewStates.Visible;
                x -= (dragItem.Width / 2);
                y -= (dragItem.Height / 2);
                FrameLayout.LayoutParams lp = new FrameLayout.LayoutParams(new ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams(width, height));
                lp.SetMargins(x, y, 0, 0);
                dragItem.LayoutParameters = lp;
                break;
        }
    };
```

Any idea why?

Answer (score 0):

Use RelativeLayout with only one TestView.handle the  touch event and and change the text view margin.

Comment: That did the trick! Any idea why it only works with recent APIs?

Comment: It should work with all API version. Relative layout is there from android API 1.